# On the "correct way" of writing vector components horizontally

Tags: calculus, soft-question, vectors

As the title states, I'm concerned about what's the correct way to write a vector, let's say

$$\vec{v} = v_x \hat{e}_x + v_y \hat{e}_y + v_z \hat{e}_z$$

in the form of comas separated values. Should I write

$$\vec{v} = (v_x,v_y,v_z)$$

or

$$\vec{v} = \langle v_x,v_y,v_z \rangle$$

or maybe

$$\vec{v} = \{v_x,v_y,v_z\}$$

So this is a notation question: what's the "correct way" (if there is) to do this? Is there any difference? Is there any notation that denotes if the vector intends to be readed vertically or horizontally?

Comment: The third notation should probably never be used - the braces mean "set", and in particular, sets do not have order, but the order of components very clearly matters.

Comment: If the vector is to be read vertically, but you would like to write it horizontally, a common way of doing this is writing : $(x,y,z)^T$, here the letter $T$ means "transpose" and turns a row vector (more formally a covector) into a column vector.

Comment: You will see both the round brackets $(\cdots)$ and the angled brackets $\langle \cdots \rangle$ used for vectors, and maybe others (but not set braces). There's no universally accepted "correct way".

Comment: In 2-D when discussing both open real intervals and ordered pairs, it is good to use $<a,b>$ for an ordered pair and $(c,d)$ for an open interval, to avoid confusion. And tell your readers.